# extension of bounded holomorphic function on the disk

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be a bounded holomorphic function defined on the open unit disk in the complex plane. Is it true that $f$ could always be extended to a Hölder continuous function on the closed disk?

Comment: Consider $f(z):=e^{\frac {-1} {1-z}}$.

Comment: This is a reasonable question to ask when one is first studying Hardy spaces, but it might have been more suitable on MSE. I must confess that I don't think I would immediately have arrived at the (standard) solution given by @user64494 if someone had not shown it to me a long time ago

Comment: With hindsight: a good way to think about how one find such examples is to recall that exp is a holomorphic map from the open left-half plane to the (punctured) unit disk. So you are just looking for holomorphic functions from the disk to the left-half plane which are bounded on the imaginary axis, and which don't converge to a common limit as $z\to \pm i \infty$.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you for mentionning Hardy spaces! I never learned it. I had a look on wiki and I think it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. It is enough to look at the plot drawn with Maple.

```
plot(evalc(Re(exp(-1/(1-exp(I*t))))), t = -.1 .. .1, y = -1 .. 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, if the function has some singularities on the boundary then it can not be extended even continuously. I should have put some more assumptions. Thank you for the nice maple plot.

Comment: @LUX: Consider $g(z):=e^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-z}}}$.